# This title is not the answer

Tags: riddle, english

> When it comes to perspectives, the second is fun
>   The third is just fine in a romantic tongue
>
> Without this, to say you have lots might be trouble
>   In fact it's so helpful you might order double
>
> One might rave about this and become enamored
>   Or think it's the same as a square famous hammer
>
> I've only had one of the seven in sight
>   I think the short version's the opposite of right

Mix them together and what have you got?
Something this puzzle most surely is not!

Edit: Whoops, forgot about this puzzle! Here's a hint!

> Each line in the formatted area is a reference to a part of the answer. LogicianWithAHat is on the right track!

Comment: I suspect the title has something to do with it! >:)

Comment: @mmking It's not, I'll give you that one for free. =P

Comment: Is the title the answer?

Comment: The title probably won't make sense until you solve the puzzle

Comment: I'm pretty sure I  know what the `square famous hammer` is, which *might* also help with the `one of the seven`, but other than that I'm stumped.  Tricky!

Comment: I think the short version's the opposite of right... short version of what? If the answer to my question reveals a major part of the puzzle... let us stay puzzled.

Comment: The answer is a sentence with 7 words? (title has 6)

Comment: @Bobson, What is the square famous hammer and the one of seven in sight? Maybe something about Thor?

Comment: @MarkN - `Or think it's the same as a square famous hammer` - The letter `E`, or something that can be confused as it.  `e = mc^2`, from MC Hammer.  Originally, I wasn't thinking clearly, and was thinking that the result was C -> Sea -> Seven seas (of which you can only see one at a time), but that doesn't flow from E.  Thor's hammer (Mjolnir) *is* famous, but it's not square.

Comment: @VictorHenry is it PUZZLES ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building off of LogicianWithAHat's answer:

- A note on the 'rave' and 'square hammer' lines

  > Both provide an 'E', thus two 'E''s are in the answer
- The double letter is

  > 'SS'
- 'One of the seven' refers to

  > 'seas' (one 'C')
- 'Opposite of Right' is

  > 'Left', often abbreviated 'L' (as in "UUDDLRLRBA")

Which gives us

> "CLUELESS"

...which this puzzle most surely is not!

Comment: Nailed it! I hope the title makes sense now. =P

Comment: Curse the fact that I needed to sleep! Well done!

Comment: @VictorHenry: Yes, and I'll add that I enjoyed this puzzle immensely.

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat: As I said, my answer simply builds upon the foundation provided by yours. I was headed in completely the wrong direction on the two 'perspectives' hints, and your was just so obviously correct I kicked myself for not thinking of it! And without that 'U', I doubt I would have thought to consider 'CLUE' as a possible partial answer.    tl;dr: I stand upon the b̶a̶c̶k̶s̶ *hats* of giants.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like each line/couplet gives a letter, and those will provide the answer:

When it comes to perspectives, the second is fun

> Second person, so you or **U**

The third is just fine in a romantic tongue

> Following from the first line, something to do with the third person in French. Assuming letters again, we get elle (she) or **L**

Without this, to say you have lots might be trouble
In fact it's so helpful you might order double

> You can't say the word 'lots' without the letter 'l', and it appears twice together in many words (though the same is trued of 'o', 't' and 's')
> Taking Deusovi's comment into account, it could well be **ZZ** - without 'z', you can't say zillions

One might rave about this and become enamored
Or think it's the same as a square famous hammer

> The letter **E** - a colloquial term for ecstacy, and equivalent to mc<sup>2</sup> - a famous hammer (U can't touch this) squared

I've only had one of the seven in sight
I think the short version's the opposite of right

> Opposite of right is either **left** or **wrong** - let's assume left, here, and I think we're meant to take the left/first character of whatever 'the seven' is.
> Seven Wonders of the World! The Pyramids of Giza are the only one left standing. So, taking **P** as the first character, then

Mix them together and what have you got?
Something this puzzle most surely is not!

> Mix them together suggests scrambling the letters
> So we have **U, L, ZZ, E** and **P** which in some order give the answer to the puzzle

Answer attempt:

> **Puzzle**. *This* title is not the answer, but the title of this stackexchange site is! Not entirely convinced, though. I'm reasonably sure that U, L and E are correct

UPDATE:

> "One of the seven" might refer to the seven seas, giving us the letter 'c'
> If so, we'd have 'u', 'l', 'e' and 'c', plus whatever the double letter is and "the opposite of right". That does assume that all of the lines are letters, though, which I'm less sure of now

Comment: To add on, for stanza 2: I think it might be referring to "Z" - "lots" can be "zillions" or something similar, and the second line is telling you to double it. We have a U,Z,Z,L, and E, and the last line is probably telling us to anagram.

Comment: In which case 'one of the seven' probably brings in a p

Comment: This is not correct, but you're on the right track.

Comment: The overall answer did feel like a bit of a stretch. Are any of my letters correct?

Comment: For part 2, I believe it should actually be ["bella"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bella), which is fine or good in Italian(?), a romantic language. Or "Belle" in French.

Comment: "bien" is probably a better French interpretation. And the 'lots' line could come out as "two". U-bien-two -> Ubuntu? Though I can't see how that would tie in with the rest of the puzzle

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat Everything in your UPDATE spoiler is correct. Everything in your most recent comment is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't made this fit with *all* the lines, but is the answer

> WEEK?

*When it comes to perspectives, the second is fun*

> The second day of the week (Monday or Tuesday, according to what convention you use).

*The third is just fine in a romantic tongue*

> "Fine" translated into French? There are a few words I've come up with, but none of them resembles "Tuesday" or "Wednesday".

*Without this, to say you have lots might be trouble

In fact it's so helpful you might order double*

> Perhaps a reference to the double E in "week" (E appears in "you hav**e** lots")?

*One might rave about this and become enamored

Or think it's the same as a square famous hammer*

> Thursday is named after the Norse god Thor, who's famous for having a hammer.

*I've only had one of the seven in sight*

> "The seven" - days of the week.

*I think the short version's the opposite of right*

> Wrong? Left?

*Mix them together and what have you got?

Something this puzzle most surely is not!*

> The puzzle is not *weak* (homophone of week); it's a strong puzzle!

Comment: Nope! +1 for the try, though!

Comment: I thought it was this too, now I'm really confused.